# Tkinter with pickle. Pyinstaller executable file problem

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pickle, executable

I'm trying to create an executable app on (MacOS). The app doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
root=Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
test={"test"}
with open('test.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(test, f)
filename='test.pkl'
try:
    model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
    Label(text='loaded',fg="red").pack()
except:
    Label(text='An error occurred.',fg="red").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**Terminal:**
`pyinstaller --onefile --windowed Yourfile.py`

Comment: Maybe someone can find a solution at this link.
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't help us to help you.

Comment: Hi Finn friend @AKX When I tried to create App with pyinstaller there are two files created in "dist" file. One of them 'Unix executable file' other one 'Application'. Unix executable file works, but the other one doesn't work. The Application doesn't work. Do you know why? Where it save pickle file "test.pkl" I think the problem that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the alternative solution but not with the Pyinstaller.
I used **Pyinstaller** instead of **py2applet**

Step 1: -Go to terminal

```
pip3 install py2app
```

Step 2:

```
py2applet --make-setup yourfile.py
Wrote setup.py
```

and

```
rm -rf build dist
```

Step 3: -Configured your setup file.

```
APP = ['yourfile.py']
DATA_FILES = ["test.pkl"]
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': False,}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Step 4: -Go terminal and then;

```
python setup.py py2app -A
```

Your App will be created in the "dist" file.

If you need more information look at the https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: if you want to share your app use without -A "python setup.py py2app"